# i am trying to get results for specific attributes? Why am i getting this error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get results for specific attributes? Trying to extract month and day of the week from Start Time to create new columns then filer to get new data frame

```py
import pandas as pd
    
CITY_DATA = {'chicago': 'chicago.csv',
             'new york city': 'new_york_city.csv','washington': 'washington.csv'}


def load_data(city, month, day):
    df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA[city])

    df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

    df['month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month
    df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name


    if month != 'all':
        months = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june']
        month = months.index(month) + 1


        df = df[df['month'] == month]


    if day != 'all':
        df = df[df['day_of_week'] == day.title()]

    return df


df = load_data('chicago', 'march', 'friday')
print(df.head())
```

AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'weekday_name'

Comment: your question is mostly code, explain what are you trying to do as well

Comment: A pandas timestamp does not have an attribute titled 'weekday_name', it does however have an attribute titled 'day_name'.  In would try chnaging the line ```df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name``` to ```df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.day_name```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214194/error-in-reading-stock-data-datetimeproperties-object-has-no-attribute-week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the following line:

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name
```

Change it to:

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.day_name()
```