# AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'day_name'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, weekday

I am using pandas day_name() function but its giving attribute error as below:

```
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', freq='D', periods=3))
```

```
s

0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-02
2   2018-01-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
s.dt.day_name()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-75cff12ad412> in <module>()
----> 1 s.dt.day_name()

AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'day_name'
```

pandas documentation has the same example. Don't know why it's not working.

Comment: does `s.dt.strftime("%A")`  work ?

Comment: @FObersteiner Oops! You are correct

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Worked for me when I tried in my iPython notebook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214194/error-in-reading-stock-data-datetimeproperties-object-has-no-attribute-week